# Getting ResolverFactory injection issue when injecting resolver

Tags: angular, angular-resolver

Consider myself as a newbie.  I have created my own Resolver class and trying to inject it in my feature module. But it is throwing me following error:

```
core.js:4352 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CivilStatusModule)[CivilStatusResolver_Factory -> CivilStatusResolver_Factory -> CivilStatusResolver_Factory -> CivilStatusResolver_Factory]
```

Added following code in feature module:

```
providers: [CivilStatusResolver]
```

And in the CivilStatusResolver class I have added Decorator as below:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CivilStatusResolver implements Resolve<boolean> {
  constructor(private civilStatusService: CivilStatusService) {}
```

What is the missing part in the above implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The resolver is supposed to be in the Feature Module right ?
So instead of providing  `providedIn: 'root'` try giving `providedIn: FeatureModule` and remove `CivilStatusResolver` from `providers` array or vice versa.